# To undo a calculation and subtract it from the running total

Tags: c#

This is a simple calculator. It performs calculations. However, every time it calculates I save that total and add it to a running total. But when I type in undo, the running total disappears and the previous calculation is not subtracted from the running total. Can someone please help me? This is suppose to be in memento format. So when I undo, a stack is removed or a total from a previous calculation. I am struggling with that.

```
 class Calculator
 {
    public Stack<double> result= new Stack<double>();
    double total = 0;

    public void Add(double a, double b)
    {
        total += a + b;
        Console.WriteLine("Sum:{0}", total);
        result.Push(total);

    }
    public void Sub(double a, double b)
    {
        total += a - b;
        Console.WriteLine("Difference:{0}", total);
        result.Push(total);

    }
    public void Mul(double a, double b)
    {
        total += a * b;
        Console.WriteLine("Product:{0} ", total);
        result.Push(total);

    }
    public void Div(double a, double b)
    {
        if (b!=0)
        {
            total += a / b;
            Console.WriteLine("Quotient:{0}", total);
            result.Push(total);

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Cannot divide by 0");
        }
    }

    double GetTotal()
    {
        return total;


    }
    void Undo()
    {
        if (result.Count==0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("UNDO IS NOT AVAILABLE");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Running total:{0}", total);

    }
    void clear()
    {
        while (result.Count !=0)
            result.Pop();
        total = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Running total:{0}", total);
    }
    static int Main()
    {
        Calculator cal=new Calculator();
        string line="";
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter (Clear, Undo, Exit, Expression):");

            if (line.ToLower() == "exit")
                break;
            else if (line.ToLower() == "undo")
                cal.Undo();
            else if (line.ToLower() == "clear")
                cal.clear();
            else
            {
                double a, b;

                Console.WriteLine("Write the first number");
                double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out a);

                Console.WriteLine("Write the second number");
                double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out b);

                Console.WriteLine("Write the operand (+, -, /, *)");
                char.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out char c);


                if (c == '+')
                    cal.Add(a, b);
                if (c == '-')
                    cal.Sub(a, b);
                if (c == '*')
                    cal.Mul(a, b);
                if (c == '/')
                    cal.Div(a, b);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your undo command doesnt try and remove anything so....

Comment: In your Undo function, you're simply returning the value of total without performing any manipulation on it...What did you expect would happen?

Comment: `Can someone help me?` is not a programming question.  As is, your code seems to not implement UnDo and it seems to know that.  I guess your Stack will store the last action?  If so it will need to store more than a double - you also have to store the last action taken so you know how to apply the value, no?

Comment: Why not just do `result.Clear()` instead of popping off all of the items individually? You're overcomplicating that, unless there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things you need to fix here.

First, you never assign anything to `line`, so your code immediately falls into the `else` block for "Expression". So not only is `Undo()` not working, but I don't see how the `Clear()` or `Exit()` methods could be working either. Something like this will help with that by assigning to `line`:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter (Clear, Undo, Exit, Expression):");
    line = Console.ReadLine();

    if (line.ToLower() == "exit")
        break;

    //Rest of the code left out for simplicity...
}
```

Note that this considers invalid input as "Expression" and false down the `else` path, so you might want to consider explicitly checking for `line.ToLower() == "expression"` and giving an error message otherwise.

Also consider changing to a `switch` statement. It's not required by any means, but a little easier to maintain and read, IMO. You should also probably do a case-insensitive `Equals()` [with this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_StringComparison_) rather than converting the input to lowercase.

As for the actual implementation of your `Undo()` method, since your last action is just one item down on the `Stack`, just `Pop()` the top item off and `Peek()` at the `Stack` for your previous total:

```
void Undo()
{
    if (result.Count==0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UNDO IS NOT AVAILABLE");
    }

    result.Pop(); //Remove current total from last expression
    total = result.Peek(); //Take previous total

    Console.WriteLine("Running total:{0}", total);
}
```

This should get you most of the way there. They may be other things that you'll need to fix as well. I did test the undo and clear functionality and they seem to work as expected, but did not test anything else (other than basic + and - expressions).

Comment: Yeah, seems like a pretty natural use of `Pop` and `Peek`. Otherwise what's the point of using a stack if you aren't going to leverage it where it makes sense?